# Minimum and Maximum values of Effective Resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Assume we have resistors of resistances $R_1$, $R_2$, $\ldots$ , $R_n$. Let these resistances be connected in a network. Are the following statements true?

$(i)$ Effective Resistance is maximum when the resistances are connected in series

$(ii)$ Effective Resistance is minimum when the resistances are connected in parallel

How do we prove/disprove these claims?

Comment: Please share your research on what you have so far. We can't do all your homework for you.

Comment: There seems to be a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426562/minimum-and-maximum-resistance

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. I think you may use Mathematical induction to prove it. $2$ resistors are right, if $N$, get $N+1$.

Comment: The network need not necessarily be full of series and parallel connections. How do you induct from $4$ resistors to an Unbalanced Wheatstone Bridge?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. User of induction shouldn't be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

All the resistance are real, positive values. Assume there are many resistors.
Given for a parallel system:
$$\frac{1}{R_T}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{R_n}$$
Since positive numbers:
$$\frac{1}{R_T}>\frac{1}{R_1}$$
Let's say that R_1 is the lowest resistance.
$$\therefore\space R_1>R_T$$
So the total resistance in parallel is always smaller than the smallest resistance.

If we look at a series system:
$$R_T=R_1+R_2+\ldots+R_n$$
As before can simplify to
$$R_1<R_T$$

This shows that a parallel system is always less than the smallest resistance while a series system is always more than the smallest, thus the resistance in series $>$ resistance in parallel.

The proof would become more complicated if we consider all possible combinations, and have commented to you a duplicate question with an answer.